# How to fill array with elements in a .txt file

Tags: c

I have a dynamic 2D float array and a file with both strings, integers(number of floats in the line) and float numbers.

```
M = (float**)malloc(num_lines * sizeof(float));

for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++){
   M[i] = (float*)malloc(num_columns * sizeof(float));
}
```

Example:

```
2
John 3 5.5 89.5 30.67 0.00
Mary 4 78.9 67.4 67.3 9.0 0.00
(null)
```

The number of lines is the one on the file + 1 and the number of columns is the highest integer + 1 (5 in this case) because the 0.00 marks the end of each line.
How do I load *only* the floats into memory? I've tried different types of loops with `fgets` and `strtok` but it doesn't work due to the different types of variables.

The code is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++){
            fgets(buf, 1000, aux);
            name = strtok(buf, " ");
            col = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
            for(j = 0; j < num_columns; j++){  
                M[i][j] = atof(strtok(NULL, " "));
                if(M[i][j] == 0.00){
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: So your question in not how to fill an array but how to read floating point values from a file which contains text and floating point values. Where is your code with `fgets` and `strtok`?

Comment: `M = (float**)malloc(num_lines * sizeof(float*))`; (you are allocating a block of `num_lines` **pointers** here). Better as `M = malloc (num_lines * sizeof *M);` In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) For columns, `M[i] = malloc (num_columns * sizeof *M[i]);` will do. If you always use `sizeof` the dereferenced pointer to set type-size -- you will never get it wrong...`

Comment: I don't even have a `fgets` and `strtok` that remotely works for what I need because I don't know how to save only the float values.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added to the post

Comment: Your file does not contain ints or floats, it is all text.  Reading text and parsing it as floats or ints is *very* different from reading ints and floats.

Comment: @WilliamPursell but is there a way to read those numbers as floats? Everything I've tried returns an array full of 0.00 or -0.00

Comment: How are you computing `num_columns`?  Is it an arbitrary large number that is sufficient to hold the data, or are you reading the file to determine the row with the hight number of entries before you allocate the array?

Comment: @WilliamPursell `num_colums` is the highest integer after the names + 1 because of the 0.00 at the end of each line

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  Are you reading the file twice?  Or are you approximating it before you read the file?

Comment: I'm reading it line by line with a `fgets` and saving the highest number. There won't be a problem of needing more columns than specified in the file.

Comment: Is the file format something you control? Because there is way too much information, thus it is easy to get an invalid file: you don't need the size, either at the beginning or the the individual entries, and you certainly don't need the 0.00.

Comment: @Neil The file format is not something I control, and I need the name strings for other functions. I agree that the size is unnecessary and I guess the 0.00 can be ignored, it's because each line has to have an extra column.

Comment: It would probably be smaller memory impact to separate the `float numbers[]` from the `char names[]` and pack them all in there, having a third table linking them together, `{ char *name; size_t offset, no; }`, but this makes adding numbers difficult. It depends on your use case.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(M[i][j] == 0.00){`  this is comparing a `float` variable to a `double` literal.  NOT a good idea.  suggest: `if( M[i][j] == 0.00f ){`  Notice the trailing `f` on the literal, which makes it a `float` value

Answer (score 0):

This sort of parsing is a bit of a pain, but is a good exercise to do every now and again.  This is relatively easy with `scanf`, but `scanf` is not suitable for anything but toys.  (It is literally impossible to correctly handle anything robustly, since even a simple `"%d"` format specifier leads to undefined behavior on certain input.)  Unless you are willing to read the file twice to determine the maximum size of a column, you can't preallocate the entire array.  Instead of that, I would suggest doing something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>                                                                 
#include <err.h>                                                                   
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <string.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
/* sample input                                                                    
2                                                                                  
John 3 5.5 89.5 30.67 0.00                                                         
Mary 4 78.9 67.4 67.3 9.0 0.00                                                     
*/                                                                                 
FILE * xfopen(const char *, const char *);                                         
void * xmalloc(size_t);                                                            
int get_row_count(FILE *in, char **line, size_t *cap, const char *name);           
float * parse_line(const char *s, int lc);                                         
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(int argc, char **argv)                                                        
{                                                                                  
        int lc = 0;                                                                
        char *line = NULL;                                                         
        size_t cap = 0;                                                            
        FILE *in = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;                        
                                                                                   
        int rows = get_row_count(in, &line, &cap, argv[1]);                        
        float **M = xmalloc(rows * sizeof *M);                                     
        for( lc = 0; lc < rows && getline(&line, &cap, in) > 0; lc += 1 ){         
                M[lc] = parse_line(line, lc + 1);                                  
        }                                                                          
        if( lc != rows ){                                                          
                warnx("invalid input: missing some rows");                         
        }                                                                          
        for( int i = 0; i < lc; i++ ){                                             
                float *f = M[i];                                                   
                for( int j = 0; j < f[0]; j++ ){                                   
                        printf("%f\t", f[j + 1]);                                  
                }                                                                  
                putchar('\n');                                                     
        }                                                                          
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
float *                                                                            
parse_line(const char *s, int lc)                                                  
{                                                                                  
        /* Skip the name */                                                        
        char *end;                                                                 
        while( *s && ! isspace(*s) ){                                              
                s += 1;                                                            
        }                                                                          
        int siz = strtol(s, &end, 10);                                             
        if( siz <= 0 || ! isspace(*end) ){                                         
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Invalid input on line %d", lc);                
        }                                                                          
        float *f = xmalloc((1 + siz) * sizeof *f);                                 
        f[0] = siz;                                                                
                                                                                   
        for( int i = 1; i < siz + 1; i += 1 ){                                     
                f[i] = strtof(end, &end);                                          
        }                                                                          
        while( isspace(*end) ){                                                    
                end += 1;                                                          
        }                                                                          
        if( *end == '\0' || strcmp(end, "0.00\n") ){                               
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Invalid input on line %d", lc);                
        }                                                                          
        return f;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
get_row_count(FILE *in, char **line, size_t *cap, const char *name)                
{                                                                                  
        if( getline(line, cap, in) <= 0 ){                                         
                if( feof(in) ){                                                    
                        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Empty input");                         
                } else {                                                           
                        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", name);                             
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        char *end;                                                                 
        int rows = strtol(*line, &end, 10);                                        
        if( rows <= 0 ){                                                           
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "invalid row count: %d", rows);                 
        }                                                                          
        if( *end != '\n' ){                                                        
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "unexpected input on line 1");                  
        }                                                                          
        return rows;                                                               
}  

                                                                                   
FILE *                                                                             
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)                                         
{                                                                                  
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :         
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;                                     
        if( fp == NULL ){                                                          
                perror(path);                                                      
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return fp;                                                                 
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void *                                                                             
xmalloc(size_t s)                                                                  
{                                                                                  
        void *rv = malloc(s);                                                      
        if( rv == NULL ){                                                          
                perror("malloc");                                                  
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return rv;                                                                 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I sort of need it in a single, function , like as simple as possible. It's part of a bigger program the floats are going to be used in math operations.

Comment: @tylerdjt So refactor it into a single function.   This demonstrates one way to parse the input, which is the core of your question.  Implementation details are your responsibility.

Comment: Immediately bail if any exception happens and let the OS clean it up; I kind of like it. Simple.